# running java servlets as independent process

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm very new to java/tomcat, and wondering if it is possible to make a java servlet for tomcat that will start when tomcat itself starts, i.e. independently of any request received, and which will keep running till tomcat stops? Furthermore, could such a servlet have unlimited access to the machine on which it is running, or is it essentially sandboxed by tomcat?

I already have something similar in Python, where a main process running with root privileges starts a sub-thread that contains a simple web server. Any requests coming in are then able to make changes to the machine as root, on basis of the root privileges. The motivation is to speak to a microcontroller via a browser-based GUI available over an intranet (so security is not an issue, it just seems like a very easy way of allowing people to remotely control lab equipment). I'm curious if this could be done in the java/tomcat ecosystem...

Comment: Servlets by definition are only processed when a request comes in. Are you asking about starting a background process as soon as Tomcat boots? Also are you sure your background process needs to receive requests?

Comment: Yes to both, I guess you could call it some sort of model-view-controller where tomcat is the controller, the web-browser is the view, and the background process is the model. But the controller always need to keep track of the model (because the microcontroller can also change the model), regardless of any user input, and it would make life simpler to do it all within tomcat rather than play around with pipes/sockets between tomcat and another process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

implement the method init() in your servlet, and add:

```
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

in web.xml file.

If you add permissions on jvm on this host, you could access to host resources: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

Comment: By default the JVM won't need any configuration to access any host resources. Tomcat will have permissions to do whatever the user Tomcat is running as has.

Comment: you could configure all permisions with policy file

Comment: You don't need to configure all permissions. They are available by default. The policy file is there to limit permissions. In the case of a sandboxed application (applet or app deployed via Java Web Start) the policy file can be used to open permissions; however, in that case it is rarely useful unless it is an application deployed to machines you have full administrative control over (because the policy file on all machines have to be updated).

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat doesn't have a sandbox, it's not like a Java Applet. It has all the permissions of the user you use to run it. So if it's running as root user it will have root privileges (Please be careful).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want a background process running that accepts requests and then does something to the server Tomcat is running on.

You don't need any background process. Tomcat itself will dutifully process any incoming HTTP requests then execute the appropriate servlet based on the configuration in web.xml (or configuration and/or convention of whatever framework you used to write your app).